# a strange use of typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I have never see a  grammar in c++ like this before:

```
typedef int (callback)(int);
```

what really  does this really mean?I just find that if  I create a statement

```
  callback a;
```

It's effect is very very similar to a forward  function declaration.

below is the code I  had written

```
#include<cstdio>

int callbackfunc(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return i*i;
}

// you can also use typedef int (callback)(int) here!
typedef int (*callback)(int);

void func(callback hook)
{
    hook(hook(3));
}

int main()
{
    func(callbackfunc);
    getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

You can use

```
typedef int (*callback)(int);//this is very common to use
```

in this code,but if we change it to

```
typedef int (callback)(int); //I'm puzzled by this !
```

this will also get the same result!

and I know `typedef int (*callback)(int)`  and  `typedef int (callback)(int)`
are two completely different stuff.

Comment: i found a same question at that link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer   and there is an awesome answer. I can advise that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its because of the fact that *in the parameter declaration*, the *function-type* is adjusted to become a *pointer-to-function-type*.

```
typedef int type(int); 
typedef int (*type)(int);
```

The first typedef defines a type which is called `function-type`, while the second typedef defines a type which is called `pointer-to-function-type`. In the parameter declaration, function-type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type.

§13.1/3 (C++03) says,

> Parameter declarations that differ only in that one is a function type and the other is a pointer to the same function type are **equivalent**. **That is, the function type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type (8.3.5)**.

```
[Example:
    void h(int());
    void h(int (*)()); // redeclaration of h(int())
    void h(int x()) { } // definition of h(int())
    void h(int (*x)()) { } // ill-formed: redefinition of h(int())
]
```

---

#### An interesting example of the exclusive usage of function-type

Suppose you've a typedef, defined as:

```
typedef void funtype();
```

then you can use this to define *member-function* as:

```
struct A
{
   //member function declaration. 
    funtype f; //equivalent to : void f();
};

void A::f() //definition
{
  std::cout << "haha" << std::endl;
}
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
        A a;
        a.f(); //call member function
}
```

Output:

```
haha
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/hhkeK

Comment: You, sir, you really know your C++.

Answer (score 3):

It's because a function implicitly becomes a function pointer where necessary. These are identical:

```
func(callbackfunc);

func(&callbackfunc);
```