# Who can help me explain the use of typedef in C++?

Tags: c++, typedef

I am so confused with this code in the book :

```
typedef int (*healthCalcFunc) (const GameCharacter&)
```

and I understand that
`typedef double* PDouble`, means the word `PDouble` can be used to declare a pointer to `double`.

But I can't figure out the meaning of `typedef int (*healthCalcFunc) (const GameCharacter&)`

Is there anyone can help me to explain this?

Thanks in advance

:)

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef int (*healthCalcFunc) (const GameCharacter&);
```

It introduces a name called *healthCalcFunc* for a type which describes a function-pointer, taking one parameter of type `const GameCharacter&` and returning an `int`.

So this means, if you've a function as:

```
int some_function(const GameCharacter&)
{
    //...
}
```

Then you can create a pointer-object which would point to the above function as:

```
healthCalcFunc pfun = some_function;
```

and then use `pfun` in place of `some_function` as:

```
some_function(args);  /normal call

pfun(args);  //calling using function pointer 
             //it is exactly same as the previous call
```

And benefit with this approach is that you can pass around `pfun` (or `some_function`) to other function  as:

```
void other_function(healthCalcFunc pfun)
{
    //..
    pfun(args); //invoke the function!
    //..
}

healthCalcFunc pfun = some_function;

other_function(some_function);  
other_function(pfun);
```

Here `other_function` will use the function pointer to invoke the function. That way, next time you can pass another function matching the function signature to `other_function` and `other_function` will invoke that another function instead.

Comment: typedef does not define a new type. typedef defines a new name for a type.

Answer (score 5):

In cases like this, operator precedence tends to get in the way.

What this creates is an alias (named `healthCalcFunc`) for the type "pointer to a function taking a reference to a const GameCharacter as its parameter and returning an int".

1. `int`: return type
2. `(*healthCalcFunc)`: Pointer to function -- must be in parens to bind the `*` to the name instead of the preceding `int`, which would declare a function returning a pointer instead of the desired pointer to a function.
3. `(const GameCharacter &)`: the parameter list for the type of function this will point at.

Comment: always funny that a parameter can be const :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a [function pointer](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) - hopefully your book will have explained these somewhere; if not, your favourite search engine should be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

That is typedef for a function pointer for functions which return `int` and take `const GameCharacter&` as an argument.

You can create a function pointer using `healthCalcFunc hp = &MyFunc;` then use it as `int n = (*hp)(GameCharacter());`. Here `MyFunc` will have this signature: `int MyFunc(const GameCharecter&);`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function type definition. At first glance, it's strange, but you'll get used to it. basically, what it says is, define a type named `healthCalcFunc`, whose return value is an integer, and takes a constant `GameCharacter` reference as its only argument.

In general, the form of a function pointer declaration is as follows:

```
typedef return_type (*new_function_typename)(typeof_arg1, typeof_arg2, ...);
```

And you can use it like this:

```
new_function_typename functor;
functor = some_other_functions_name;
// or
functor = dlsym(dlopen_handle, "some_function_name"); // for dynamic loading

int retval = functor(arg1, arg2);
```