# what's the meaning of "typedef void (*__handler)(int)" ?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer)

Could you please help me understand the meaning of this typedef and how to use it?

```
typedef void (*__handler)(int)
```

without the "typedef", I know the rest is a function pointer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This defines a type name for the function pointer. Using this, `__handler` is now a type alias for a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`.

```
void myFunction(int)
{
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    __handler functionPtr = &myFunction;

    // ...
}
```