# Make a block that accepts a block as argument

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-blocks

```
void (^block)();
void (^block1)(int);
```

The first line declare a block.

The second line declare a block that takes an integer argument.

Now I want a block that accepts another block as an argument:

```
void (^block2)(<another block>);
```

How would I do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a typedef, e.g.

```
typedef void (^BlockTypeToAccept)();
void (^block)(BlockTypeToAccept inner_block);
```

or combine them directly:

```
void (^block)( void (^inner_block)() );
```

Comment: Very clear. Would you explain a little about how typedef void (^BlockTypeToAccept)();
 work. I mean, usuallly we do typedef double CGFloat;. Now the type being defined is not even on the far right. That's why it's confusing.

Comment: @HaryantoCiu: The `typedef` is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer.