# How are signal signatures in `boost::signals2` implemented?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, implementation, boost-signals2

I have been using `boost::signals2` for some time now in my projects. To my shame, I still do not understand how they are implemented *under the hood*. My problems already start at the very definition of a signal. How is a definition such as

```
boost::signals2::signal< void (bool, double) >
```

handled? I can see from the implementation details that the signature becomes a template parameter that is aptly named `Signature`. However, I do not understand the syntax. Is this syntax permitted by the C++ standard? How can a signal "store" the function signature when it is provided in this form?

I already tried looking at the sources, but was unable to find an explanation for this syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd guess `Signature` is used as function signature. google-mock uses the same thing to describe and bind function signatures of mocked interfaces, apparently it's valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this syntax is allowed; the type it denotes is a *reference to function taking a `bool` and `double` and returning `void`*. If we were to `typedef` it, it would be awkward, because the name would sit in the middle:

```
typedef void Signature(bool, double);
```

With the new alias syntax is becomes slightly more readable:

```
using Signature = void(bool, double);
```

The parallel with pointers to functions would be:

```
typedef void (*Pointer)(bool, double);

using Pointer = void (*)(bool, double);
```

Afterwards, there are template tricks to tease apart the various elements (extract the return type, and the type of each argument).

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. Maybe that's too broad a question, but how can I look up/learn this stuff myself? I tried reading the C++ standard document myself, but is there an "easier" way?

Comment: The C++ standard is perhaps the harder way about it. There are several "tutorial" or "advanced" books, if you look up at the description of the C++ tag you'll get a list of useful questions on this site. One, notably, is a [list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
// In header: <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>
template<typename Signature, ... /* Omitted other args for clarity */> 
class signal : public boost::signals2::signal_base {
public:

  // In your case, typedef would be evaluated as
  //typedef void (bool, double) signature_type    
  typedef Signature  signature_type;
```

More info on how typedef can be used with function pointers:
[Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer)