# typedef int (*pf) needs explaining

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

Generally,  we use `typedef` to get alternate names for datatypes.
For example --

```
typedef long int li; // li can be used now in place of long int
```

But, what does the below typedef do?

```
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
```

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) to the rescue!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typedef function pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer)

Comment: @milleniumbug: Did you try it? Syntax error!

Comment: Its typedef function pointer but this question emphasizes easy understanding. since its more lucid.

Comment: @milleniumbug: Unfortunately, cdecl simply says "syntax error" on this code.  Perhaps you should check it yourself before suggesting something like this.  :)

Comment: @lnafziger I think the real question is why OP finds the former to be "valid" but the latter to be weird. cdecl is still useful in the sense that knowing "... pf [is a] pointer to function (int, int) returning int" means that `typedef int (*pf) (int, int)` is just giving a shorthand name for a "function (int, int) returning int".

Comment: @roliu: If the OP doesn't know what this code is (and is therefore asking the question), do you really think that he is going to be able to make that translation and figure that out?

Comment: @lnafziger My point was that he doesn't need to figure anything out. He needs to get rid of the barrier that he's created mentally between an `int` and a function pointer. If he didn't consider them to be so different then perhaps he wouldn't have asked the question. I can imagine also having this question and entering in `int (*pf) (int, int)` into cdecl; at which point I might think "huh... I guess you... could just declare a function pointer `pf foo = ...`. Hm... Cool!" Or perhaps the real question is "how do you use functions as variables?" Basically my answer to your question is, "yes".

Comment: @roliu: Well, I think that he is asking this question because of a basic lack of understanding which makes it very difficult to "reason" things out.  This site is for people of all skill levels, and something that is simple for you is not always simple for a novice programmer.  His specific question was "what does the below typedef do" indicating that he is not familiar enough with the language to figure it out on his own and he needs help...  So, my response to you is, "Not everyone is at your skill level, so please give him a break and just answer the question."  :-)

Comment: @lnafziger I was just pointing out that cdecl could help OP here; that was literally the only point of my comment. I'm not sure where you construed that I thought he wasn't allowed to ask this question. I suggested a train of thought where cdecl would prove fruitful... that's it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
```

This means that variables declared with the `pf` type are pointers to a function which takes two `int` parameters and returns an `int`.

In other words, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*pf)(int,int);

int addUp (int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int main(void) {
    pf xyzzy = addUp;
    printf ("%d\n", xyzzy (19, 23));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef long int li;
```

assigns alternate name `li` to type `long int`.

In exactly the same way

```
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
```

assigns alternate name `pf` to type `int (*) (int, int)`. That all there is to it.

As you probably noticed, `typedef` declarations follow the same syntax as, say, variable declarations. The only difference is that the new variable name is replaced by the new type name. So, in accordance with C declaration syntax, the declared name might appear "in the middle" of the declarator, when array or function types are involved.

For another example

```
typedef int A[10];
```

declares `A` as alternate name for type `int [10]`. In this example the new name also appears "in the middle" of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function pointer prototype.  You can then declare a function as an argument something like this:

```
void RegisterCallback(pf your_callback_func);
```

Then you can can call the function passed as a func ptr:

```
...
your_callback_func(i, j);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` has the name `pf` and it is for a function pointer that takes two integers as arguments and returns an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` works as:

Define `unknown type` with `known types`.

So it defines function type that takes two int argument and return int.