# C++ understanding cocos2d-x use of function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef, cocos2d-x

I am experimenting around with extending cocos2d-x CCMenuItem components and came across something I have not seen before in C++. It would be helpful if someone would elaborate on what is going on with their function pointer declarations

The base class for most cocos2d-x objects is CCObject which has the following definition

```
class CC_DLL CCObject : public CCCopying
{
public:
    // Code omitted 
};

// The part in which I have a question about
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_SCHEDULE)(float);
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_CallFunc)();
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_CallFuncN)(CCNode*);
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_CallFuncND)(CCNode*, void*);
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_CallFuncO)(CCObject*);
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_MenuHandler)(CCObject*);
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_EventHandler)(CCEvent*);
typedef int (CCObject::*SEL_Compare)(CCObject*);

#define schedule_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_SCHEDULE)(&_SELECTOR)
#define callfunc_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_CallFunc)(&_SELECTOR)
#define callfuncN_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_CallFuncN)(&_SELECTOR)
#define callfuncND_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_CallFuncND)(&_SELECTOR)
#define callfuncO_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_CallFuncO)(&_SELECTOR)
#define menu_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_MenuHandler)(&_SELECTOR)
#define event_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_EventHandler)(&_SELECTOR)
#define compare_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_Compare)(&_SELECTOR)
```

So outside of the CCObject class, but within the cocos2d namespace, there exists a declaration for function pointers and helper macros to use them. Am I correct in calling these declarations for function pointers?

I understand that typedef is associating a keyword with a type (See [Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer)) and that the return type is must be void and the function must have one mandatory argument of CCObject *. However I am lost in understanding its appropriate usage, scope, and how C++ treats passing a function through another function.

**Question 1**

I am not following how to interpret the scope of the declared function pointer. In their declaration, they show the function pointer being scoped by the CCObject class. How should I interpret this? Does this mean when it is assigned that function belongs as a member function to CCObject? This is confusing to me as it is defined outside of the class body but scoped with CCObject.

```
typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_MenuHandler)(CCObject*);
```

**Question 2**

In the cocos2d-x CCMenuItem class, it has a static factory method defined below

```
// How does C++ treat the this? Is a function treated like an object here?
static CCMenuItem* create(CCObject *rec, SEL_MenuHandler selector);



   CCMenuItem* CCMenuItem::create(CCObject *rec, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
{
    CCMenuItem *pRet = new CCMenuItem();
    pRet->initWithTarget(rec, selector);
    pRet->autorelease();
    return pRet;
}

bool CCMenuItem::initWithTarget(CCObject *rec, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
{
    setAnchorPoint(ccp(0.5f, 0.5f));
    m_pListener = rec;
    m_pfnSelector = selector;
    m_bEnabled = true;
    m_bSelected = false;
    return true;
}

// A snippet from CCMenuItem header
protected:
    CCObject*       m_pListener;
    SEL_MenuHandler    m_pfnSelector; // member variable which stores a pointer to a  function?
    int             m_nScriptTapHandler;
};
```

So does this typedef mean that when I pass a function it, I am passing by value with a pointer? How would C++ handle this if the function was not passed by pointer. Is a function treated like an object with a copy constructor?

I appreciate any help and advice. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void (CCObject::*)(CCObject*)` is a *method pointer* type (one type of *pointer to member*), not an ordinary function pointer. It's a pointer that can point to an instance method of the `CCObject` class that takes a parameter of `CCObject*` type. The type of class it's a method of is part of the pointer type (denoted by the `CCObject::`), similar to the parameters (because underneath, a pointer to the "current object" is a hidden parameter to all instance methods, `this`).

The `typedef` simply defines `SEL_MenuHandler` to be a synonym for that method pointer type.

To use a method pointer, you need to provide both an instance to act as `this`, as well as the arguments, using a syntax like this:

```
CCObject* object;
CCObject* anotherObject;
SEL_MenuHandler methodPointer;
(object->*methodPointer)(anotherObject);
// or equivalently: ((*object).*methodPointer)(anotherObject);
```

> How would C++ handle this if the function was not passed by pointer.
>   Is a function treated like an object with a copy constructor?

In C/C++, it is not possible to have an expression of "function type" or "method type". Any time you try to get something of "function type", it is automatically converted to a "pointer to function" type.