# C++11 define function type capture by reference

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I turn below function into a typedef?

```
auto fn = [&] (int x) { doSomething(x, 3); }
```

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `decltype` to get the *exact* type:

```
  auto fn = [&] (int x) { doSomething(x, 3); };
  using lambda_type = decltype(fn);
```

But if you merely want to know a *compatible*, more general type, say for passing the lambda as argument to another function, you can use `std::function<void(int)>` (as Joachim mentions).

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
using my_function_type = std::function<void(int)>;
```

Comment: @linquize Then use `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef std::function<void(int)> my_function_type;
```

Works in VS2012