# Please explain this use of typedef

Tags: c, function, pointers, typedef

Here is the code:

```
// Global Definitions/Declarations:

typedef void * LOGHANDLE;

typedef LOGHANDLE (STD_CALL *LogOpen_T)
       (unsigned char *, 
        unsigned char *, 
        unsigned long, 
        unsigned long *);

LogOpen_T LogOpen;

// Inside some function:
    ...
    LogOpen = (LogOpen_T)ImportSymbol(moduleHandle, "LogOpen" );
    if (LogOpen == NULL)
    {
         err = -2;
    }
    ...
```

I am not able to understand how the `typedef` is been used here. Please explain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer

Comment: Remove the word "typedef" ... do you understand it then? If not, your problem isn't with typedef. if so, then you shouldn't have any trouble understanding the typedef.

Comment: @JimBalter: I still remember how irritated I was seeing a `typedef` for a function pointer for the first time.

Comment: @alk I can't relate. Like I said, if you already understand declarations of function pointers -- and that's the annoying part because of how C buries the name being declared inside a bunch of syntax -- then understanding a typedef is straightforward, as it just declares the name as a synonym for the type rather than being a variable of the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typedef` itself defines a type alias for a pointer to a function where the function seems like:

```
void * STD_CALL f(unsigned char *, unsigned char *, unsigned long, unsigned long *);
```

The variable `LogOpen` is the actual pointer-to-a-function. Later the result of `ImportSymbol` is cast to the pointer-to-a-function.

Answer (score 2):

`LOGHANDLE` defines a pointer which can point to anything. 
`LogOpen_T` defines a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

this is a pointer to a function of prototype

```
LONGHANDLE functionname
   (unsigned char *, 
    unsigned char *, 
    unsigned long, 
    unsigned long *);
```

example of use

```
LOGHANDLE mylogfunction
   (unsigned char *, 
    unsigned char *, 
    unsigned long, 
    unsigned long *){/* code*/}


LogOpen_T function_handle = (LogOpen_T)(&mylogfunction);
```