# Typedef function with void * pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm trying to implement a function defined in a library but I'm having problems to use it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer) question help me to implement it, but I couldn't use the function.

Here is the typedef:

`typedef void (*paillier_get_rand_t) ( void* buf, int len );`

And here is how I implement it:

```
void get_rand(void* buf, int len) {
  buf = (void *)rand();  // I don't know if it works but isn't the problem
}
```

And here how I create the pointer to the function and call it.

```
   int modulus = 4;
    void* buf;
    paillier_pubkey_t* pub;
    paillier_prvkey_t* prv;
    paillier_keygen(modulus, &pub, &prv, &get_rand);
```

Question 1) How I send the parameters buf and len?
Question 2) Now the error is different:

```
reference to `paillier_keygen(int, paillier_pubkey_t**, paillier_prvkey_t**, void (*)(void*, int))' undefined
```

The function `paillier_keygen` is used to generate the respectives key for the algorithm and the function `get_rand` is used to obtain the randomness needed by the probabilistic algorithms.

I'm implementing this typedef because I need to do it to be able to use the lib.

EDIT:

I found one function who is already defined and I can use called `paillier_get_rand_devurandom`.

/*
    These functions may be passed to the paillier_keygen and
    paillier_enc functions to provide a source of random numbers. The
    first reads bytes from /dev/random. On Linux, this device
    exclusively returns entropy gathered from environmental noise and
    therefore frequently blocks when not enough is available. The second
    returns bytes from /dev/urandom. On Linux, this device also returns
    environmental noise, but augments it with a pseudo-random number
    generator when not enough is available. The latter is probably the
    better choice unless you have a specific reason to believe it is
    insufficient.
*/

```
void paillier_get_rand_devurandom( void* buf, int len );
```

If I used like before

```
paillier_keygen(modulus, &pub, &prv, paillier_get_rand_devurandom(buf, 4));
```

I get `error: invalid use of void expression`

If I used like this:

```
paillier_keygen(modulus, &pub, &prv, &paillier_get_rand_devurandom);
```

I get:

```
undefined reference to `paillier_get_rand_devurandom(void*, int)'
undefined reference to `paillier_keygen(int, paillier_pubkey_t**, paillier_prvkey_t**, void (*)(void*, int))'
```

The library is included. Here I add more info about the signatures:

/*
  Generate a keypair of length modulusbits using randomness from the
  provided get_rand function. Space will be allocated for each of the
  keys, and the given pointers will be set to point to the new
  paillier_pubkey_t and paillier_prvkey_t structures. The functions
  paillier_get_rand_devrandom and paillier_get_rand_devurandom may be
  passed as the final argument.
*/

```
void paillier_keygen( int modulusbits,
            paillier_pubkey_t** pub, paillier_prvkey_t** prv, paillier_get_rand_t get_rand );
```

/*
  This is the type of the callback functions used to obtain the
  randomness needed by the probabilistic algorithms. The functions
  paillier_get_rand_devrandom and paillier_get_rand_devurandom
  (documented later) may be passed to any library function requiring a
  paillier_get_rand_t, or you may implement your own. If you implement
  your own such function, it should fill in "len" random bytes in the
  array "buf".
*/

```
typedef void (*paillier_get_rand_t) ( void* buf, int len );
```

Comment: Try `paillier_get_rand_t fnPtr = &getRand;` and pass `fnPtr` as the argument.

Comment: I would guess that `paillier_pubkey_t** pub;` is wrong, and instead you should have `paillier_pubkey_t* pub;` and pass to the function with `&pub`.  (i.e. it probably expects a pointer to memory that it can access, you are giving something that will crash to access).

Comment: `buf = (void *)rand();  // I don't know if it works but isn't the problem` certainly makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: You define a type `paillier_get_rand_t` but then you never use it anywhere. That indicates to me that you're either leaving off vital code, have a typo somewhere, or you're entirely clueless about what you're doing (in which case you should probably stop. What are you trying to do? If what you're trying to do is understand every nook and cranny of C++ and you have no greater purpose, stop. That's a waste of time. C++ is packed to the brim with overlapping features. You probably already know some equally valid way of accomplishing the same things that this construct might do.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare It's the first time that I work with this kind of functions and pointers. I need to implement it to work with the library wich help me with the encryption in a protocol that I'm implementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. First of all I import the library like extern, because   [paillier.h](http://acsc.cs.utexas.edu/libpaillier/#general) is written in C and I'm using C++.

Just like this:

```
use #include <gmp.h>
extern "C"{
    #include "paillier.h"
}
```

After that I also compiled with `-lpaillier` and also `-lgmp`.

The final code would be:

```
paillier_pubkey_t* pub;
    paillier_prvkey_t* prv;
    paillier_keygen(1024, &pub, &prv, paillier_get_rand_devurandom);
```

There is no need to define any additional function.

Comment: Have same problem, great to see the solution.

Comment: @1a1a11a Could you give me how to compile with -lpaillier and also -lgmp. In order to generate makefile, I did like "./configure LIBS=-lgmp" and "./configure LIBS=-lpaillier", but error occurred.

Comment: @user2642459 what are you compiling?

Comment: @1a1a11a I'm compiling both libraries gmp and paillier.

Comment: you don't need anything special when you compile gmp

Comment: @1a1a11a I solved my problem. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing a bit here, because you don't show the prototype of all the functions (and their documentation), but you almost certainly want this instead:

```
paillier_pubkey_t* pub;
paillier_prvkey_t* prv;
paillier_keygen(modulus, &pub, &prv, &get_rand);
```

With get_rand probably doing something like:

```
void get_rand(void* buf, int len)
{
    char* bytes = (char*)buf;
    for (int i = 0; i != len; ++i) {
        bytes[i] = rand() & 0xff;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then why does he typedef `paillier_get_rand_t` if that's all he wants?

Comment: I have a feeling the `paillier` library declares that typedef and he's trying to implement the corresponding function. I made a few guesses based on what idiomatic C interfaces tend to look like.

Comment: @Cameron is right, i'm trying to implement the corresponding function to the library `paillier`. I updated the code with more information and the error that I'm getting with your modifications.

Comment: @Niemand: Your question's much clearer, thanks. However, I still don't have enough info to figure out what's not working -- what is the declared signature of the `paillier_keygen` function? (This is what you're trying to use, and so we need to know what it looks like in order to help you use it correctly.) Are you linking against the appropriate library? (The error message you get looks an awful lot like a linker error that would arise if the function was declared and used properly but its compiled code could not be found.)

Comment: @Cameron I completed even more the question, sorry to don't that from the beginning. I think that I found the function I have to use, I'm getting the first error again.

Comment: @Niemand: Right, that helps, thanks. It seems I surmised correctly -- both my sample call and your second one with `&paillier_get_rand_devurandom` are correct. Judging from the errors, it looks like you've included the right headers and the code compiles properly, but it fails at link time because the `paillier` library isn't being linked in. You need to link against `libpaillier`. How to do this exactly depends on your compiler, operating system, and whether the library is static or dynamic.

Comment: @Cameron I'm compiling with the option -lpaillier and it works, dosn't show any error like: `library not found`.

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing and invoking the value of get_rand_function when you state the following:

```
(*get_rand_funtion)(&buf, 4)
```

Since the declared return type is void, the compiler interprets the result of the expression as void, which is not a valid type for a function parameter.  If you desire is to pass a pointer to the function paillier_keygen then @Cameron code is correct.  At least in C99 and earlier you may not bind values to function pointer.