# How to call the functions of paillier library

Tags: c++, c, call, gmp, paillier

I want to call the functions of paillier library (http://acsc.cs.utexas.edu/) in C++ environment. I found out the helpful site ([Typedef function with void * pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308155/typedef-function-with-void-pointer)) and followed the comment answered Feb 10 '15 at 12:40 from Niemand. But, my code output error messages as follows.

[image]

I appreciate your any comments to solve the problems. My detail procedures is as follows.

1. Compiling and installing gmp library (with default option)

   - gmp.h is generated in /usr/local/include
   - libgmp.a, libgmp.so, libgmp.la, etc are generated in /usr/local/lib
2. Compiling and installing paillier library (with default option)

   - paillier.h is generated in /usr/local/include
   - libpaillier.a is generated in /usr/local/lib
3. Sample code for paillier library test

[image]

4. Setting properties for project in eclipse to use libraries

   In [Properties] - [C/C++ Build] - [Settings] - [Tool Settings],

   - [GCC C++ Compiler] - [includes] - [Include paths] : input "/usr/local/include"
   - [GCC C Compiler] - [includes] - [Include paths] : input "/usr/local/include"
   - [GCC C++ Linker] - [Libraries] - [Library search path] : input "/usr/local/lib"
   - [GCC C++ Linker] - [Libraries] - [Libraries] : input "gmp", "paillier"

[image]

My environment's version is as follows

- ubuntu : 18.04.2
- eclipse : 2019-03
- gmp : 6.1.2
- paillier : 0.8

Comment: What happens if you switch the link order? That is, use `input "paillier", "gmp"`

Comment: @NikosC. I can't believe that the problem is the link order. You're genious! Thank you so much.

Comment: OK, nice! Made that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you switch the link order? That is, use input "paillier", "gmp". Especially with static libraries, link order is important.