# how to understand the following code about typedef in C

Tags: c, typedef

Does anyone know how to understand the fourth line of the code shown below?

```
typedef short Signal;
typedef struct Event Event;
typedef struct Fsm Fsm;
typedef void (*State)(Fsm *, Event const *);
```

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer

Answer (score 2):

It declares `State` as a `typedef` for `void (*)(Fsm *, Event const *)`.

`void (*)(Fsm *, Event const *)` is a function pointer, pointing to a function that takes two arguments, `Fsm *` and `Event const *`, and returns `void`.

More information: [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/3425536) and [Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295432/3425536)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the typedefs one by one:

- The first line creates an alias for the type `short`. Now you can write `Signal xyz = 0;` and it would be equivalent to writing `short xyz = 0;`
- The second and third lines let you write declarations of variables of the two `struct` types without the `struct` keyword. In other words, you can now write `Fsm myFsm;` instead of writing `struct Fsm myFsm;`
- The last line declares a type `State` that corresponds to a `void` function pointer taking a pointer to `Fsm` and a pointer to `Event`.

The syntax may be a little tricky because of all the parentheses and the name being typedef-ed not being at the end of the declaration. You can tell it's a type definition for a function pointer, because the name of the type is in parentheses, and is prefixed with an asterisk. The rest of the `typedef` looks very much like a function signature, so the result is easy to read.