# C++: Peculiar typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, v8

From [my understanding](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/), typedef syntax is:

```
typedef existing_type new_type_name;
```

However, in [Chrome's v8 namespace](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/namespacev8.html), there are many typedefs that seem to work with some other syntax. For example,

```
typedef void(*  FunctionCallback )(const FunctionCallbackInfo< Value > &info)
```

There are two things I don't understand:
1- FunctionCallbackInfo< Value > is a class defined in the namespace, while FunctionCallback isn't; isn't the existing type supposed to come first?
2- There are no spaces seperating the *existing_type* and *new_type_name*

What is the right way to read this?

EDIT: I am taking all typedef information in [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/).

Comment: Give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer

Comment: btw, many people prefer alias declarations instead of typedefs. For those the syntax is more straightforward, `using new_name = existing_type_id;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding of the `typedef` syntax is a bit inaccurate. It's not:

```
typedef existing_type new_type_name;
```

It's more like:

```
typedef declaration;
```

So your example is a declaration of a `typedef` for a function pointer type named `FunctionCallback`, which returns `void` and takes a reference to a `const FunctionCallbackInfo< Value >` as its only parameter.

Comment: Yep. Basically, prefixing any valid declaration with `typedef` creates a type alias instead of a variable.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to understand a typedef is not to think of it as

```
typedef existing_type new_type_name;
```

The best way to understand this is to compare it with a regular variable or a class member declaration. For example:

```
char *ptr_func;
```

This declares `ptr_func` as a pointer to a character. Now, when you stick a `typedef` in front of that, you're essentially turning this into a type definition, not a variable declaration:

```
typedef char *ptr_func;
```

This now declares `ptr_func` as a type that represents a pointer to a character.

Now, let's look at your example as a variable declaration:

```
void(*FunctionCallback )(const FunctionCallbackInfo< Value > &info);
```

What is this? Well, this declares a `FunctionCallback` which is a pointer to a function that takes a `const FunctionCallbackInfo<value> &` parameter, returning a `void`.

So, it logically follows that sticking a `typedef` in front of this turns this into a definition of `FunctionCallback` as a type which is a pointer to a function that takes a `const FunctionCallbackInfo<value> &` parameter, returning a `void`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void(*  FunctionCallback )(const FunctionCallbackInfo< Value > &info)
```

defines the type `FunctionCallback` as a pointer to a function taking `const FunctionCallbackInfo< Value > &` and returning `void`. I keep promoting this rule, which I find extremely useful in reading complicated pointer declarations: [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Oldies but goldies ;)