# GLib HashTable passing the functions as the parameters

Tags: c++, c, glib

I am learning the GLib GHashTable source code.
You can see the source code from the link here.

https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/ghash.c

https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/ghash.h

```
GHashTable *g_hash_table_new (GHashFunc  hash_func,
                                GEqualFunc key_equal_func)
```

**g_hash_table_new**  function create the basic hash table here.
My question is the parameters.
The first two parameters "**GHashFunc hash_func, GEqualFunc key_equal_func**" are passing to the function.

In the **ghash.h**, there are no hash_func and key_equal_func, they are just symbols. They will be replaced by the real hash functions. 
How do the two functions become parameters here?

I know there are some hash functions in ghash.h files, like:

```
guint g_int_hash (gconstpointer v) 
guint g_str_hash (gconstpointer v)
```

Those functions will be passing to "g_hash_table_new " during the running time to replace "hash_func" and "key_equal_func ". 
But I do not know what kind of technique is that?
How to passing a function as a parameter to another function and replace it during the running time.

Thanks

Comment: They are Function Pointers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pass param is a point, you define hash compute function. all function process is callback function. hash table just pass param  to your equel function.