# Error C2914: sort function unable to identify which version of an overloaded predicate to use

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, predicate

I have recently started trying to teach myself C++ and am new to the board. I have created a strut called permuted_index, and a vector of permuted_index objects called perm_index.

I have written an overloaded predicate called "stringCompare" to be used with the sort function to sort either a vector of strings or a vector of permuted_index objects. However, when I try and run my program get error C2914 - which as I understand it means that the sort function can not identify which of version of stringCompare to use.

I have been looking at this for days and am completely stumped! I can force my program to work by commenting out one version of the predicate, but I would really like to understand the underlying program and would appreciate any help. I have provided everything that I think will help anyone looking at this below but if you need any more information please let me know.

This is the permuted index strut;

```
struct permuted_index{

std::string word ;

std::vector<std::string>::size_type line ;
std::string::size_type position ; 

std::vector<std::string> full_line ;
std::vector<std::string> rotated_line ; 

std::string before_word ;
std::string after_word ; };
```

This is the overloaded predicate;

```
#include <string>  
#include <vector> 
#include "split.h" 
#include "Permuted_index.h"

using std::string ; 
using std::vector ; 

bool stringCompare(const string& x, const string& y) {

vector<string> p ;
vector<string> q ; 

p = split(x) ; 
q = split(y) ; 

return p[0] < q[0] ;
}


bool stringCompare(const permuted_index& x, const permuted_index& y){

return x.rotated_line[0] < y.rotated_line[0] ; 
}
```

This is the split function called above;

```
vector<string> split(const string& s) 
{
    vector<string> ret ;
    typedef string::size_type string_size ; 

    string_size i = 0 ; 

    while(i != s.size())
    {
    while(i != s.size() && isspace(s[i]))
    {
        ++i ;
    }

    string_size j = i ; 

    while(j != s.size() && !isspace(s[j]))
    {
        ++j ;
    }

    if(i != j)
    {
        ret.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i)) ;
        i = j ;
    }
}

return ret ;
}
```

The line within my main() program that is causing the error is;

```
sort(perm_index.begin(), perm_index.end(), stringCompare) ;
```

and the the exact error message is:

```
error C2914: 'std::sort' : cannot deduce template argument as function   argument is ambiguous
```

Comment: How `perm_index` is defined?

Comment: Hi Alex Lop, I'm not sure I understand the question please can you elaborate? I initiate the perm_index as vector<permuted_index> at the beginning of my int main() code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, using a cast seems a little iffy to me. But this works:

```
void foo(std::vector<permuted_index> &pi)
{
    using Compare = bool (*)(const permuted_index &, const permuted_index&);
    Compare cmp = stringCompare;
    std::sort(pi.begin(), pi.end(), cmp);
}
```

This declares a type alias, `Compare`.

Before C++ 11 this was done with what is called a `typedef`, as in:

```
typedef bool (*Compare)(const permuted_index &, const permuted_index &);
```

These both just say that `Compare` is a name for a function that takes two `permuted_index` objects and returns a `bool`. (Technically `Compare` is a pointer to a function but function names by themselves are also pointers.) The C/C++ syntax for function type names is not exactly the easiest thing to parse but if you read the `typedef` from the inside out it in sort of a left-right order (the "spiral" rule) it says `Compare` is a pointer (the asterisk) to a function taking two `permuted_index` references (the parentheses enclosing the reference declarations to the right) and returning `bool`) You can find [a nice SO description of these topics here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer) and there are various tutorials on function pointer syntax (evidence in and of itself that it isn't the simplest aspect of C/C++) around the web, such as [this article that explains the spiral rule.](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Anyway, `Compare` is an alias for a function of precisely the type that `sort` expects for a comparator when sorting `permuted_index` objects. We then declare a pointer instance, `cmp` that points to `stringCompare`. The compiler now knows precisely the type of `cmp` so there is no ambiguity as to which `stringCompare` we can assign to `cmp`.

As another aside, `cmp` *is* a pointer and you could actually write

```
Compare cmp = &stringCompare;
```

In C++, the name of a function by itself "decays" to a pointer to that function, so this is redundant and I left it out in my example.

Another approach is to an inline lambda. Lambdas are a new part of the language that allow you to declare a function in-place. This is a very useful syntax for things like comparators that are often only used once, when the algorithm is called. Like function pointers, the syntax takes a bit of getting used to. [Here is a nice SO article on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) Basically the `[]` signals that this is a simple lambda (not a "closure" of any sort), this is followed by the arguments to the lambda, which is then followed by its body. (You can optionally declare the return type right after the arguments as

```
[](const permuted_index &, const permuted_index &) -> bool { ... }
```

but this isn't usually necessary as the compiler can infer the type from the function body.)

Anyway, as with the `typedef` above, this approach works because the lambda has declared what the arguments are so the right `stringCompare` will be chosen, and the type of the lambda is obvious to the compiler so there is no confusion over which function type to use to figure out the second template type in `sort`.

```
void bar(std::vector<permuted_index> &pi)
{
    std::sort(pi.begin(), pi.end(), 
              [](const permuted_index &a, const permuted_index &b) 
              { return stringCompare(a,b); });
}
```

I believe the issue is that the `Compare` template parameter is completely independent of the type being compared - there isn't currently a way for the library to specify that its type should have the signature of a comparison between the two value types being sorted on. (Though I'm not exactly sure why SFINAE doesn't remove the possibility of using the first overload.)

Comment: Hi sfjac, thanks for for having a look at my problem but I'm afraid that a lot of what you have done is also completely new to me! Please could you explain in a bit more detail what is happening in your first alternative? Exactly what is "Compare" - it does not look like a newly defined function or a library function to me? I think you are using a pointer but I don't understand why (I thought the main benefit of pointers was in relation to memory allocation.

Comment: Hi sfjac, Thank you for that very detailed reply and the links. I really appreciate you taking the time to provide all of this and the links. I can't say I understand it all right now, but it will keep me busy for a while!

Comment: Cool. Please +1 / check answered if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
sort(perm_index.begin(), perm_index.end(), 
     static_cast<bool(*)( const permuted_index &, const permuted_index & )>(stringCompare) );
```