# Passing Function Pointers to Functions, c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am trying to get a function to call another function through a pointer, I have gone through some posts and have tried doing it but I keep getting errors.
Print is the function that I want apply to call. Apply should print all the data when print is called.

I get the error: Variable has incompatible type void

```
      void print(double x) //function I want to pass
{
cout << x << endl;
} 

void apply(vector<double> data, void (*f)(double))
    { //function with pointer to other function print
           for(int i = 0; i< data.sizeof(); i++)
               f(data[i]);
        }
```

Comment: `data.sizeof()` should be `data.size()`

Comment: Use C++11 and its `std::function` and its lambda functions

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the whole code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print(double x) //function I want to pass
{
    cout << x << endl;
} 

void apply(const vector<double>& data, void (*f)(double))
{ //function with pointer to other function print
    for(size_t i = 0; i< data.size(); i++)
        f(data[i]);
}

void test()
{
    vector<double> data;
    data.push_back(1.0);
    data.push_back(2.0);
    data.push_back(3.0);

    apply(data, print);
}
```

Comment: stdafx.h and _tmain are windows-specific, neither of which are necessary to address the OP's question.

Comment: It's nothing with stdafx.h and _tmain. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to clamp to [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or use and [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) for such job:

```
void apply(const vector<double>& data, std::function<void(double)> f)
{ //function with pointer to other function print
    for(size_t i = 0; i< data.size(); i++)
        f(data[i]);
}
```

or

```
void apply(const vector<double>& data, auto f)
{ //function with pointer to other function print
    for(size_t i = 0; i< data.size(); i++)
        f(data[i]);
}
```

Using auto will depend on the compiler since this usage is only available after c++14 standard.

Comment: I think `auto` is introduced in C++11, isn't it?

Comment: @Elyasin, yes but no for using it in function parameters, that was introduced in c++14

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
void apply(const vector<double>& data, void (*f)(double) ) {
   for( int i=0; i<data.size(); ++i )
       f(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly what the error is. Your code seems to work (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print(double x) //function I want to pass
{
    cout << x << endl;
}

void apply(const vector<double>& data, void (*f)(double)) { //function with pointer to other function print
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        f(data[i]);
}

int main() {
    vector<double> v{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9};
    apply(v, print);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
4.4
5.5
6.6
7.7
8.8
9.9

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

The only changes I made were:

- change `data.sizeof()` to `data.size()`, but I think you would have figured that already (a `vector` does not have a public member function called `sizeof()`)
- not necessary to make it work, but good practice: the first parameter for `apply` is (in general) best declared as `const vector<double>& data`. That is you pass a reference to a data type/structure that won't be modified (for memory consuming objects that is expected to be more efficient)

Comment: If I used a typedef for the function pointer parameter, do I have to initialize the typedef to point to the function in main?

Comment: Not sure how your question is meant. This answer shows an example of a typedef defined function pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4295495/1566187

Comment: And according to this example you could define `typedef void (*Func)(double);` and change the signature/function to `void apply(vector<double> data, Func f)`. The rest remains unchanged.