# Are infinite typedef function pointer inheritances possible?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, types

**TL;DR**

Is it possible, for a `typedef` function of type `foo` to point to another type `bar` and so on? In my experience yes, but how is this?

**Preface**

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer) question, I tried to play around with `typedef` function pointers.
Something really interesting came out. I have *heard* that it's not possible to cast function type with `typedef`.

This is definitely true in cases such as:

```cpp
typedef existing type sometypedef(/*parameters*/);
   sometypedef testfunc{ 
                  ^
             /*Error*/
   };
```

This not only because it is impossible, but also completely useless because of `template`, but not always...

**When the magic comes in**

*Pointers* can be very handy and lead to great confusion, but really helpful when used right. Consider the following example:

We have a function `foo`, that we want to refer as a pointer.
No problem's as long as no complicated parameters.

But now want to refer both `foo`, and other variable's inside function `bar`'s parameters. Now we're stuck, because

```cpp
void* foo(/*parameters*/);
void bar(foo* f)
```

or anything like that is not allowed. We simply cannot refer to `foo`. But don't give up yet! Because here `typedef` comes useful. We can make something like

```cpp
typedef void (*newfunctype)(/*pointer parameters*/);
newfunctype* foo();
newfunctype bar(newfunctype* nf);
```

and now it works!!

**...But this was not the actual question**

Because the real question is how? How, for example the following piece of code works?:

```cpp
typedef void (*sometype)();
typedef sometype(*anothertype)(sometype);
typedef anothertype(*yetanothertype)(sometype);
yetanothertype d(anothertype);
/*etc, other initializations*/
```

We can even make functions with that stuff, like

```cpp
anothertype anotherfunc(anothertype* an, yetanothertype* sn);
```

and they... *work like charm*?

How long can these pointers to new `typedef` types be expanded? Forever?
Is this really standard c++ (or c?) syntax, or does it lead to undefined behavior?

Comment: `yetanothertype* f = new yetanothertype();` I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Why so? Isn't initializing pointers always a good idea?

Comment: You are dynamically allocating a function pointer. The free store is read-write memory, but not executable. Any attempts to use it will cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot EDIT: removed it, because it was not really part of the main question

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot The fact that the pointer itself is in non-executable memory doesn't mean that it cannot point to a perfectly fine function, which would be callable through that pointer with no problems (think `std::vector<yetanothertype>`). Of course, OP's code was value-initializing the pointer, and calling through *that* value would, of course, not lead to a happy result. OP: From the way you worded the question it's not clear to me if you know that the declaration of `d` also declares a function (there's no initialization there). Just wanted to make sure you're aware of that.

Comment: @bogdan ahh yes, declaring a pointer to pointer to function has no problem indeed, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why shouldn't it work? What's wrong with it working? Nothing really. But anyways...

typedefs only are aliases to other type. Let's start with an example :

```
using MyType = int; // same thing as typedef int MyType

MyType a;
MyType b;
```

To the eyes of the compiler, the code above becomes this:

```
int a;
int b;
```

So now you ask how your examples works. Well, let's expand the typedefs into the real types:

```
typedef int* MyType1;
typedef MyType1* MyType2;
typedef MyType2* MyType3;

MyType3 a;
```

We'll start by using a cleaner syntax :

```
using MyType1 = int*;
using MyType2 = MyType1*;
using MyType3 = MyType2*;

MyType3 a;
```

Now that the name is out of the type, it's easy to see how the compiler expands types. Let's do it manually :

```
// using MyType1 = int*;
using MyType2 = int**;
using MyType3 = MyType2*;

MyType3 a;
```

Then :

```
// using MyType1 = int*;
// using MyType2 = int**;
using MyType3 = int***;

MyType3 a;
```

Then :

```
// using MyType1 = int*;
// using MyType2 = int**;
// using MyType3 = int***;

int*** a;
```

But it's really that. Typedefs are alias to types, they are not variables nor any runtime entity. It's just the compiler writing out complex types for you by giving it a pretty name.

So no, you can't have undefined behavior by making too much typedefs. You can have undefined behavior is you misuse the types however, but that's another thing.