# Why is there a pointer pointing to nothing in this declaration of signal?

Tags: c++, c

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)
```

I can't follow this kind of explanation of syntax too clearly. I know it's simple but I'd rather watch a quick video or read a book about the style/software engineering concept of this. Basically how may I explain this as a coder?

Comment: Are you asking "What is `signal` in this declaration, and why?" [Perhaps cdecl.org will help](http://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*signal%28int%2C+void+%28*%29%28int%29%29%29%28int%29%3B). It is also one of the rare times a pointer type (in this case a function pointer) hidden in a typedef would make the code *easier* to understand and use: [it is synonymous to this](http://pastebin.com/sTPU0t2j).

Comment: I find this link extremely helpful: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: "I know it's simple" - judging by the right vs. wrong answer frequency below, I beg to differ. People seem to see `void (*` and immediately conclude this is a function pointer while they start hunting for an argument list to digest, not seeing the second `(`, the extra `)`, and the trailing `(int)`.  In this case, `signal` is a function, not a function pointer, and the syntax is anything-but-simply unless you're very comfortable with c decls.

Comment: @WhozCraig I disagree about the pointer-behind-typedef thing. You could easily write `typedef void sig_fn(int); sig_fn *signal(int sig, sig_fn *handler);` without hiding pointers. :-)

Comment: @melpomene To each his own. I believe callback function pointers and opaque handle libraries are the two places (and honestly the *only* two places) where pointer hiding in typedefs make sense. Regarding doing it without them, sure you can, and to that I defer to the single-responsibility-principle. Always nice to see someone with a different view than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)
```

`signal` is a function that takes `int` and a pointer to a function(that takes integer as argument and returns void) and returns pointer to a function(that take integer as argument and returns void)

Reference link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_signal.htm

Answer (score 1):

*func* is a function pointer that takes an int as parameter and returns nothing.

```
void (*func)(int)
```

Signal is a function that takes *int* and *func* for parameter:

```
signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)) // calling it x
```

Signal returns a function pointer from the above form, taking int for argument and returns nothing:

```
void (*x)(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, I like to explain it from inside to outside.

`void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)`

First you need to know the syntax of function pointer, when you see `void (*func)(int)`, you should be aware that this is a function pointer which can point to the function which takes an int as parameter.

Then the second part `void (*signal(int sig, ...))(int)`, you can see that there is a invocation of `signal`, and also the syntax of function pointer. Thus, the `signal` is a function which returns a function pointer, so that it can coordinate with the function pointer syntax `void (*signal(..))(int)`

PS. I think you may [learn about how to use `typedef` with function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer)

Comment: `signal` is NOT a function pointer; it *returns* a function pointer.

Comment: I have seen your answer, Thank you very much!@WhozCraig

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it from the other side, how do you create such a declaration? You can do it by following two rules:

1. To declare a function (with some argument list) returning `T`, first declare `func` as `T`. Then add the parameter list (wrapped in parentheses) after `func`.
2. To declare a pointer to `T`, first declare `ptr` as `T`. Then add `(*` before and `)` after `ptr`. Optionally, if the token following `(*ptr)` is not `(` or `[`, you can remove the parens you just added (leaving just `*ptr`).

(`func` and `ptr` are just placeholders. You can use any identifier you want.)

`signal` is a function (we'll deal with the parameters later) returning a pointer to a function (of some parameters) returning `void`. To declare this, we need to start at the end and declare `signal` as `void` (yes, I know that's not allowed):

```
void signal;
```

The next step is "... function (of some parameters) returning `void`", so we apply rule #1:

```
void signal( /* some parameters */ );
```

The next step is "... a pointer to [that function]", so we apply rule #2:

```
void (*signal)( /* some parameters */ );
```

We can't remove the parens in `(*signal)` because the following token is `(`.

The next step is "... a function (we'll deal with the parameters later) returning [that pointer]", so we apply rule #1:

```
void (*signal( /* to be dealt with later */ ))( /* some parameters */ );
```

That's the complete skeleton. Now let's take a look at the parameter lists.

The *some parameters* part is what the function-that-`signal`-returns-a-pointer-to accepts. Which is just an `int`:

```
void (*signal( /* to be dealt with later */ ))( int );
```

The *to be dealt with later* part is what `signal` itself takes, which is two parameters:

1. a signal number, `int`
2. a signal handler, a pointer to a function (taking an `int`) returning `void`

#1 is easy: `int sig`.

#2 can be done "backwards" again:

```
void func;  // func is void
```

Applying rule #1:

```
void func(int);  // func is a function returning void
```

Applying rule #2:

```
void (*func)(int);  // func is a pointer to a function returning void
```

Plugging our parameters in the declaration of `signal` finally gives us:

```
void (*signal( int sig, void (*func)(int) ))( int );
```

This is exactly the declaration you were struggling to decipher: `signal` is a function (taking `sig`, an `int`, and `func`, a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning `void`) returning a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning `void`.

This answer might not make it easier to read those declarations, but now you'll be able to create your own monstrosities of this kind. :-)

---

PS: If you want to incorporate arrays as well, there's a third rule:

3. To declare an array (of size `N`) of `T`, first declare `arr` as `T`. Then add `[N]` after `arr`.