# Callback using lambda with closures

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures, function-pointers

I'm trying to implement a callback which passes control from an Interrupt Service Routine to a member function on a c++ class. I thought *lambdas* and closures would be a convenient means of doing this, but I'm having trouble implementing it. Below is a simplified version of my code.

The issue I'm stuck on is how to store the "*function pointer*" to the "*lambda*".

```
class Gpio
{
  public:
    typedef void (*ExtiHandler)();    
  private:
    ExtiHandler handler;    
  public:
    void enable_irq(ExtiHandler handler_in) 
    { 
      // enable interrupt
      // ...
      // save handler so callback can be issued later
      handler = handler_in;
    }
};

class Button
{
  private:
    Gpio& pin;    
  public:
    Button(Gpio& pin_in) : pin(pin_in) 
    {
    };

    void button_pressed()
    {
      // do something
    }

    void init()
    {
      pin.enable_irq([this]() { this->button_pressed(); });
    }
};
```

Compiling fails with the following error message;

```
 no matching function for call to 'Gpio::enable_irq(Button::init()::<lambda()>)'candidate: void Gpio::enable_irq(Gpio::ExtiHandler) no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Button::init()::<lambda()>' to 'Gpio::ExtiHandler {aka void (*)()}' Build failed
```

How can I modify this code to resolve the compile error?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, that `enable_irq` function expects a typed **function pointer** of type `void (*ExtiHandler)()` **not a lambda** function.

That means, here

```
pin.enable_irq([this]() { this->button_pressed(); });
```

you are trying to store a lambda function(with capturing the instance) to a [typed function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer). You could have converted the lambda to a function pointer(easily) if it would have been a capture-less lambda.

See [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#def:closure_type) *<sub>(sec 7)</sub>*

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with **no
>   lambda-capture** whose constraints (if any) **are satisfied has a
>   conversion function to pointer to function** with C++ language linkage
>   having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's
>   function call operator.

Since [lambdas are not just ordinary functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and capturing it need to **preserve a state**, 
you can not find any simple or conventional solution to make them assign to function pointers.

---

### Solution - 1

The simplest solution is to use **[`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)** instead, by paying some [type erasure overhead](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/). That means, in your code, just need to change the

```
 typedef void(*ExtiHandler)();
```

to

```
typedef std::function<void()> ExtiHandler;
// or
// using ExtiHandler = std::function<void()>;
```

---

### Solution - 2

> Can this be accomplished without using the STL?

**Yes**. After making a small research on this topic, I came up with a type traits solution to store the [lambdas with closure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Dangling_references) to the equivalent typed function pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Lambda> struct convert_lambda : convert_lambda<decltype(&Lambda::operator())> {};    
template<typename Lambda, typename ReType, typename... Args>
struct convert_lambda<ReType(Lambda::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using  funPtr = ReType(*)(Args...);
    static funPtr make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
    {
        static const Lambda& lmda = t;
        return [](Args... args) {   return lmda(args...);   };
    }
};    
template<typename Lambda> using convert_lambda_t = typename convert_lambda<Lambda>::funPtr;    
template<typename Lambda> constexpr convert_lambda_t<Lambda> make_function_ptr(const Lambda& t)
{
    return convert_lambda<Lambda>::make_function_ptr(t);
}
```

**Usage:** <kbd>**[SEE LIVE EXAMPLE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LNjY013EFafkty3C)**</kbd>

1. You can now simply continue with your `Gpio` and `Button` classes, without
       changing anything.:

   ```
   pin.enable_irq(make_function_ptr([this]() { this->button_pressed(); })); 
   // or 
   // pin.enable_irq(make_function_ptr([&]() { this->button_pressed();}));
   ```
2. Or with arguments. For example

   ```
   int aa = 4;
   auto lmda = [&aa](const int a, const float f) { std::cout << a * aa * f << std::endl; };
   void(*fPtrTest)(const int, const float) = make_function_ptr(lmda);
   fPtrTest(1, 2.0f);
   ```

---

**Drawbacks:** The solution - 2:

1. is **not** capable of recognizing the *optional sequence of specifiers*.(i.e, `mutable`, `constexpr`)
2. is **not** capable of forwarding parameter pack to the traits. i.e,
   the following is not possible:

   ```
   return [](Args&&... args) { return lmda(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
   ```

Comment: Can this be accomplished without using the STL? I am developing on an embedded toolchain which doesn't have a STL.

Comment: Would be very much happy to see a solution which is also capable of the drawbacks mentioned at the end. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and code. I tried your example but found an issue when using more than one object instance. See this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CsnUVHqFkG3xmdUR

Comment: @knick The link you provided, there you have an undefined behavior (most probably because of `Gpio& pin;`, not sure). Since it is another question and has a potential for asking a new question in the community, I would recommend you to ask one question regarding it in SO. :(

Answer (score 3):

Closure object can be assigned to function pointer only if capture list of lambda is empty, in your case this condition is not met - `[this]`.

You can use `std::function` as wrapper to store your closures:

```
#include <functional>

class Gpio
{
  public:
        using ExtiHandler = std::function<void()>;
  private:
        std::function<void()> handler;
  public:
    void enable_irq(const ExtiHandler& handler_in) 
    {
      handler = handler_in;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have std library then you could implement the type erasure yourself.

Something like this ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct function
{
    struct base
    {
    virtual void call() = 0;
    virtual base* clone() = 0;
    };

    template <typename Fn>  
    struct impl : base
    {
        Fn fn_;

    impl(Fn&& fn) : fn_(std::forward<Fn>(fn)){}
        impl(Fn& fn) : fn_(fn){}

    virtual void call()
    {
       fn_();
    }

    virtual base* clone() { return new impl<Fn>(fn_); }

    };

    base* holder_;

    function() : holder_(nullptr)
    {};

    template <typename Fn>
    function(Fn&& fn) : holder_(nullptr)
    {

    holder_ = new impl<Fn>(std::forward<Fn>(fn));
    }

    function( function&& other)
    {
    holder_ = other.holder_;
    other.holder_ = nullptr;

    }

    function(const function& other)
    {
        holder_ = other.holder_->clone();
    }
    ~function()
    {
        if (holder_) delete holder_;
    }


    function& operator=(function&& other)
    {
    if (holder_) delete holder_;
    holder_ = other.holder_;
    other.holder_ = nullptr;
    return *this;
    }

    function& operator=(const function& other)
    {
    if (holder_) delete holder_;
    holder_ = other.holder_->clone();

    return *this;
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        holder_->call();
    }
};


class Gpio
{
  public:
    using ExtiHandler = function;   
  //private:
    ExtiHandler handler;    
  //public:
    void enable_irq(ExtiHandler handler_in) 
    { 
      // enable interrupt
      // ...
      // save handler so callback can be issued later
      handler = handler_in;
    }
};

class Button
{
  private:
    Gpio& pin;    
  public:
    Button(Gpio& pin_in) : pin(pin_in) 
    {
    };

    void button_pressed()
    {
      std::cout << "Button pressed" << std::endl;
    }

    void init()
    {
      pin.enable_irq([this]() { this->button_pressed(); });
    }
};

int main() {
    Gpio some_pin;
    Button b(some_pin);
    b.init();

    some_pin.handler();
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/5j2Lkp)