# Declaration of a function pointer's typedef in C++

Tags: c++, typedef

I understand that similar [questions with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer) have been asked before. I already understand the concept of a function pointer and the meaning of its declaration.  Following is my sample code of a function's pointer, where I assign the function pointer `fp_GetBiggerElement` to point to the function `GetBiggerElement`

```
    #include <iostream>

    typedef     int     (*fp_GetBiggerElement)      (int, int);
    //           ^                ^                     ^
    //      return type      type name              arguments

    using namespace std;

    int GetBiggerElement(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        int bigger = arg1 > arg2 ? arg1 : arg2;
        return bigger;
    }

    int main()
    {
        fp_GetBiggerElement funcPtr = GetBiggerElement;

        int valueReturned = funcPtr(10, 20);
        cout << valueReturned << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

What I understand is, `typedef` means to assing a new definition for a type. Usually, the `typedef` statement needs `two-parts`(or say two-arguments)

1. ***first part*** is the type which needs a new alias
2. ***second part*** is a new alias name

   ```
   typedef     unsigned  int       UnsignedInt;
   //              ^                   ^                       
   //          (original type)     (Alias)
   ```

for example, in the code above, the first part is `unsigned int` and the second part is `UnsignedInt`

```
    typedef     char *              CharPtr;
    //              ^                   ^                       
    //      (original type)          (Alias)
```

similarly, in the second example above, the first part is `char*` and the second part is `CharPtr`

**QUESTION:** I am confused with the FORMAT of the `typedef` statement for a function pointer. In the statement `typedef    int(*fp_GetBiggerElement)(int, int);`, the typical two-arguments format for `typedef` is not followed then, how is it working?

**UPDATE:** I am aware that C++11 offers another way of declaring function pointer i.e. (by `using` statment). In this question, I am only interested to understand the syntax of `typedef` statement for a fucntion pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295432/253056

Comment: @PaulR: That's the same question whose link I have posted in my OP but it doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: @skm To be more precise, it's not the syntax of `typedef`, it's the syntax of a function pointer that is different. The function pointer syntax looks the same everywhere. In declarations and in typedefs.

Comment: @bloody Not necessarily. Explicitly taking the address of a function is just as legal as using the function name directly (some prefer to show intention more clearly). Be aware that for member functions, you *must* use the address-of operator!

Comment: @Aconcagua Oh, thanks, never encountered such (for member functions I know). I deleted that comment.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best idea to think about `typedef` syntax is like declaring variable of type you want to typedef. For example:

```
char *CharPtr;// declare CharPtr to be variable of type char*

typedef char *CharPtr_t;// declare CharPtr_t to be alias of type char*
```

Similarly with function pointers:

```
int (*fp) (int, int);// declare fp as pointer to int(int, int)

typedef int (*fp_t)(int, int);// declare fp_t to be alias of pointer to int(int, int)
```

Btw, in C++11 and further you get not-so-confusing (and more powerful) alternative to `typedef` - `using`. You should be using (pun intended) it instead. Just look:

```
using fp = int (*)(int, int);// declare fp_t to be alias of pointer to int(int, int)
```

Answer (score 4):

`typedef` uses the same syntax as a variable declaration, but declares a type name rather than a variable name.

The parts are "intermingled" in a somewhat peculiar (some would call it "wtf?") way - a variable declaration has the same form as its use, which simplifies the parser and enables reusing code in the compiler.

It makes more sense if you read in a more "old-school" way:

```
int *p;
```

"`*p` is an `int`"
(Equivalent translation: "`p` is a pointer to `int`")

```
int *p, x;
```

"`*p` and `x` are both `int`s"
("`p` is a pointer to `int`, and `x` is an `int`")

```
int (*q)[3];
```

"`*q` is an array of three `int`s", or "`(*q)[x]` is an `int`"
("`q` is a pointer to an array of three `int`s")

```
int (*fp)(int,int);
```

"`*fp` is a function that takes two `int`s and returns an `int`"
("`fp` is a pointer to a function that takes two `int`s and returns an `int`")

```
int (*(*foo)())[3];
```

"`*(*foo)()` is an array of three `int`s" (alternatively, "`(*(*foo)())[x]` is an `int`) - or, in other words,
"`(*foo)()` is a pointer to an array of three `int`s" - or, in other words,
"`foo` is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to an array of three `int`s"

A slightly unreadable effect of this is that

```
int *p, x, (*q)[3], (*fp)(int,int), (*(*foo)())[3];
```

declares all of the above at once.

Answer (score 3):

That's just the syntax for function pointers.
You would see the same thing if you just declare a variable.

```
int foo; // Normal
int (*bar)(int, int); // bar is of type int(*)(int,int)
```

Personally i prefer to use `using = ...` which in my opinion is more clear.

```
using fp_GetBiggerElement = int (*)(int,int);
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax comes from the C-way of reading variables.

Ever wondered why we need an asterisk, for *every* pointer we want to declare in a single expression?

```
int *p1, *p2, p3; // p3 is not a pointer
```

C++ people generally tend to see a variable having a specific type, which can be a pointer (in other words, they see the pointer characteristics as property of the *type*). That's why they usually prefer writing

```
int* p1; // notice asterisk grouped with type
```

C people rather read as: I have a variable `p1`, and if I dereference it, I get type `int` (so `p1` being a pointer is *deduced* information, i. e. they see the pointer characteristics rather as property of the *variable*; and that's why they rather group the asterisk to the name: `int *p1;`).

Pretty similar for function pointers:

```
int (*fp) (int, int);
```

I have a variable `fp`, and if I dereference it, I get `int (int, int)`. Same pattern then for the `typedef`. On the other hand, the (new) C++ way for defining an alias reflects much better the C++ way of thinking:

```
using fp = int (*)(int, int);
```

I have a variable, and it's type is a pointer (to whatever) right from the start – well, not fully consistently, though: With C++ way of thinking, function pointers might rather look like `int(int, int)*` or maybe requiring parentheses `(int(int, int))*`, but OK, that's not the way it is (wanting to stay compatible with C being reason for).

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` declarations are similar to simple declarations but instead of declaring an identifier of a derclarator as an identifier of an object or a function they declare an identifier of a declarator as an alias for the specified type.

Consider the following examples of simple declarations

```
int x;
unsigned int a[10][20];
int unsigned ( *p )[10][20];
void ( *f )( int, int );
double h( double );
```

They declare several objects and the function `h`.

Now place in these declarations decl-specifier `typedef` (in any order relative to other decl-specifiers) and you will get that the declared identifiers become aliases of types.

```
typedef int x;
unsigned typedef int a[10][20];
int unsigned typedef ( *p )[10][20];
void typedef ( *f )( int, int );
typedef double h( double );
```

That is `x` is an alias of the type `int`. `a` is an alias for the type unsigned `int [10][20]`. `p` is an alias for the pointer type unsigned `int ( * )[10][20]`. `f` is an alias for the function pointer `void ( * )( int, int )`. And `h` in an alias for the function type `double( double )`.