# What is void (*pfunc[3])()?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have this code line in my code.
what is `void (*pfunc[3])()` ?

```
uint32_t Var1 = 1, Var2 = 2, Var3 = 3;
void (*pfunc[3])();
pfunc[0] = Var1;
pfunc[1] = Var2;
pfunc[2] = Var3;
```

Comment: Doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet does not make sense.

This

```
void (*pfunc[3])();
```

is a declaration of an array of three elements of pointers to functions of the type `void()`. Moreover there is nothing known about the function parameters.

On the other hand. this declaration

```
uint32_t Var1 = 1, Var2 = 2, Var3 = 3;
```

declares three objects of the type `uint32_t`.

So the compiler should issue at least a warning that there is no implicit conversion from the type `uint32_t` to the type `void (* )()`for statements like this

```
pfunc[0] = Var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

your example does not make too much sense bu

```
void foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

void bar()
{
    printf("bar\n");
}

void goo()
{
    printf("goo\n");
}



int main()
{
    uint64_t Var1 = (uint64_t)foo, Var2 = (uint64_t)bar, Var3 = (uint64_t)goo;
    void (*pfunc[3])();
    pfunc[0] = (void (*)())Var1;
    pfunc[1] = (void (*)())Var2;
    pfunc[2] = (void (*)())Var3;

    pfunc[0]();
    pfunc[1]();
    pfunc[2]();
}
```

`Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3` keep addresses of the functions.

`void (*pfunc[3])();` - declares an array of three function pointers

`pfunc[2]();` - dereferences the functions pointer - ie calls the referenced function

https://godbolt.org/z/VUpfLl

PS uint64_t was used because integer has to have a size at least same as the size of the pointer. My system is 64 bits so the pointers are 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to @VladfromMoscow's answer.

The syntax of the line you ask about can look a bit odd if you're not familiar with that sort of thing.  If you re-state it as:

```
typedef void (*fn_ptr_t)();   
  // fn_ptr_t is a type of pointer, pointing to a function returning void and taking no arguments.

...

fn_ptr_t pfunc[3];
  // an array of three fn_ptr_t's
```

then it *might* be a bit clearer.  Specifically, your array declaration now looks like a 'normal' array (like `int numbers[4]` for example).

You could argue that C's weird syntax has now pushed the confusion one step away into the typedef...  Try this: [Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `typedef void (*fn_ptr_t)( void );` would be better in C.  Leaving the argument list of a function empty has an explicit meaning in C++ but opens a new can of worms in C.