# typedef - Typedef without curly braces

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I'm rather new at C, but what does this syntax mean?

`typedef Value (*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args);`

From what I understand, "Value" is used here to define the type of the new name.
The part I don't understand is `(*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args);` , what does this part mean?

Comment: This is a *function pointer*, you might want to research it further. What curly braces have to do with it though?

Comment: That's a pointer to a function Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) for more detail on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Typedef function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295432/10871073).

Comment: `NativeFn` is being defined here (`Value` msu have been defined previously). Its a type alias for "pointer to function accepting an int and a pointer to Value and returning a Value".

Comment: You might be confused about curly braces because a lot of typedefs are for structure types. The braces are part of the syntax of a `struct` definition, not of `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

Others have correctly said that this:

```
typedef Value (*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args);
```

creates a typedef name `NativeFn` for a pointer-to-function type.

The syntax of `typedef`, like the syntax of C declarations in general, can be confusing. The `typedef` feature was actually added to the language after the declaration syntax had been established, and it had to be added without breaking anything else. The solution was to treat `typedef` syntactically like a storage class specifier (though it isn't one semantically). The storage class specifiers other than `typedef` are `extern`, `static`, `_Thread_local`, `auto`, and `register`.

Which means that you can understand a `typedef` declaration by replacing the keyword `typedef` by, for example, `static`. Where a `static` declaration declares an object (or function) of a certain type, a corresponding `typedef` declaration creates a type definition with the same name and type. So this:

```
static int foo;
```

creates an object `foo` of type `int` (with static storage duration), while this:

```
typedef int foo;
```

creates a type name `foo` that's an alias for type `int`.

So if your declaration had been:

```
static Value (*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args);
```

it would have defined `NativeFn` as a pointer-to-function object (with the function returning a result of type `Value`).  Replacing `static` by `typedef` means that `NativeFn` is a type name that refers to that same pointer-to-function type.

It's also important to remember that `typedef` does not create a new type. It creates a new name for an existing type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider such a record

```
Value (int argCount, Value* args)
```

It denotes a function type that has the return type `Value` and two parameters of the type `int` and `Value *`.

The identifier `Value` is declared somewhere else and can for example be an alias for a type.

To introduce an alias for a pointer type to the function type you can write

```
typedef Value (*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args);
```

So if you have a function as for example

```
Value some_function(int argCount, Value* args);
```

then you can declare a pointer to this function using the typedef alias definition the following way

```
NativeFn pointer_to_some_function = some_function;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
typedef (*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args)
```

means

`NativeFn` is a `function type(can also be called "a pointer to function" or "function pointer")` that returns `Value` and takes a `int` and a `Value *` as arguments.

If you've troubling undertsanding why and how should we use it, then read the code below, specially the comments, it'll be clear to you, what `(*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args)` means and how to use it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// note: "Value" is a type declared earlier
//       for discussions sake we're declaring our own Value type

typedef struct __value {
    int x, y;
} Value;


// now, the following tells us that:
// "NativeFn" is some function type that returns "Value"
typedef Value (*NativeFn)(int argCount, Value* args);


// okay, see how to use "NativeFn"
// for use "NativeFn" we've to declare some function first
// which takes two arguments same as "NativeFn" and return "Value"
Value someFun(int argCount, Value* args) {
    // do something argCount and args
    // at last it should return some "Value" type
    Value v = {2, 3};
    return v;
}

int main() {
    // now its time to use "NativeFn"
    NativeFn fun;

    fun = someFun; // notice we can use fun as a variable and assign a
    // function to it, which must take arguments same as "NativeFn" and returns "Value" type

    Value input = {10, 12};
    
    Value output = fun(1, &input); // note, we're calling "fun", not "someFun"

    // it'll output 2, 3, cause we're returning Value v = {2, 3} from "someFun"
    printf("(x, y): %d, %d\n", output.x, output.y);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you've any question, ask me in the comment...

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` facility is used to create aliases for types.  For example,

```
typedef int *iptr;
```

creates the name `iptr` as a synonym for the type `int *`, so you could declare pointers using

```
iptr p, q;
```

instead of writing

```
int *p, *q;
```

C declaration syntax is a bit more complicated than most people realize, especially where pointers are involved.  The basic rules are:

```
T *p;            // p is a pointer to T
T *a[N];         // a is an array of pointer to T
T *f();          // f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*a)[N];       // a is a pointer to an array of T
T (*f)();        // f is a pointer to a function returning T
T const *p;      // p is a pointer to const T
const T *p;      // same as above
T * const p;     // p is a const pointer to T
```

Things can get arbitrarily complicated - you can have arrays of pointers to functions:

```
T (*a[N])();
```

or functions returning pointers to arrays:

```
T (*f())[N];
```

or even worse atrocities.  Function pointer declarations get uglier when there are parameters in the mix; fortunately, you only need to list the parameter *types* in a declaration, not the names:

```
typedef Value (*NativeFn)(int, Value*);
```

makes things a *little* easier to follow.

That declaration creates `NativeFn` as a synonym for the type "pointer to function taking an `int` and `Value *` and returning `Value`".

Suppose you have a function defined as

```
Value foo( int argcCount, Value *args )
{
  Value result;
  ...
  return result;
}
```

If you want to create a pointer to this function named `fptr`, you'd normally declare it as

```
Value (*fptr)(int, Value *) = foo;
```

However, the `typedef` declaration above allows you to write

```
NativeFn fptr = foo;
```

Having said all that, use `typedef` *sparingly*.  The problem is that while it can create an easier-to-read ways of declaring some items, it also hides some potentially useful information.  For example, despite the `iptr` example above, it's best to *not* hide pointers behind typedefs - if someone needs to use the unary `*` operator on `p` or `q` in order to use them properly, than that information needs to be in the declaration of those items.  If someone ever needs to *call* the thing `fptr` points to, then they need to know what the return type is, the number and types of parameters, etc., but all that information is missing in the declaration that uses the typedef name.