# typedef syntax that have never seen before

Tags: c++, directx

I know typedef is used to give specific names to other types but I have never seen this syntax before.
How does this evaluate? What type is being wrapped to what?

```
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* DXGIGetDebugInterface)(REFIID, void**);
```

Comment: The cynical answer is that Windows code does lots of stuff that no-one has ever seen before. <g>

Comment: I particularly like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295451/10871073) to the duplicate question.

Comment: The modern C++ alternative way — arguably syntactically easier on the eyes — of making DXGIGetDebugInterface identifier specify the same type alias: `using DXGIGetDebugInterface = HRESULT(WINAPI*)(REFIID, void**);`